# SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.jasper..runtime.pageContextImpl.handlePageException:701'

Tags: eclipse, jsp

After successfully uploading project on bluemix I got this error

> SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class
>   'org.apache.jasper..runtime.pageContextImpl.handlePageException:701'
>   on eclipse  and on URL page I got  Exception thrown by application
>   class
>   'org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection:284'
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource
>   invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:db2://75.126.155.153:50000/SQLDB" at
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(Query

[image: Screenshot of error]

I have updated my version of jar file to db2jcc4.jar from db2jcc.jar but still facing the below issue .Please find full stack trace below:

```
{
Checking application - bluemixproject
Generating application archive - bluemixproject
Pushing application - bluemixproject
Application successfully pushed
Starting application - bluemixproject
Updated app with guid a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
Got staging request for app with id a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
Updated app with guid a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
-----> Downloaded app package (5.3M)
-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (4.0K)
-----> Liberty Buildpack Version: v1.20.1-20150729-1255
-----> Retrieving IBM 1.7.1_sr3fp10-20150708 JRE (ibm-java-jre-7.1-3.10-pxa6470_27sr3fp10-20150708_01-cloud.tgz) ... (0.0s)
         Expanding JRE to .java ... (0.9s)
-----> Retrieving App Management 1.7.0_20150729-1104 (app-mgmt_v1.7-20150729-1104.zip) ... (0.0s)
         Expanding App Management to .app-management (1.0s)
-----> Retrieving com.ibm.ws.liberty-2015.6.0.0-201507291255.tar.gz ... (0.0s)
         Installing archive ... (0.9s)
-----> Retrieving com.ibm.ws.liberty.ext-2015.6.0.0-201507291255.tar.gz ... (0.0s)
         Installing archive ... (0.7s)
-----> Retrieving and installing client jar(s) from com.ibm.ws.icap.clientJars.db2.zip (0.0s)
-----> Warning: Liberty feature set is not specified. Using the default feature set: ["jsf-2.0", "jsp-2.2", "servlet-3.0", "ejbLite-3.1", "cdi-1.0", "jpa-2.0", "jdbc-4.0", "jndi-1.0", "managedBeans-1.0", "jaxrs-1.1"]. For the best results, explicitly set the features via the JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY environment variable or deploy the application as a server directory or packaged server with a custom server.xml file.
-----> Auto-configuration is creating config for service instance 'SQL Database-fl' of type 'SQLDB'
-----> Liberty buildpack is done creating the droplet 
-----> Uploading droplet (194M)
Starting app instance (index 0) with guid a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 2015.6.0.0/wlp-1.0.9.cl50620150610-1749) on IBM J9 VM, version pxa6470_27sr3fp10-20150708_01 (SR3 FP10) (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0028A: Processing included configuration resource: /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/runtime-vars.xml
[INFO    ] CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 4.594 seconds
[INFO    ] CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
[INFO    ] CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host *  (IPv6) port 61432.
[INFO    ] CWSCX0122I: Register management Bean provider: com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.provider.dump.JavaDumpBeanProvider@fc8940ad.
[INFO    ] CWSCX0122I: Register management Bean provider: com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.provider.logging.LibertyLoggingBeanProvider@b72bc7f3.
[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.liberty.connector.
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.liberty.connector has been bound to default_host.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://18sfpg6jl5m:61432/IBMMGMTRest/
[INFO    ] CWWKZ0018I: Starting application myapp.
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module bluemixproject has been bound to default_host.
[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: bluemixproject.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://18sfpg6jl5m:61432/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application myapp started in 0.802 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [json-1.0, jpa-2.0, icap:managementConnector-1.0, beanValidation-1.0, jdbc-4.0, managedBeans-1.0, cloudAutowiring-1.0, jsf-2.0, jsp-2.2, servlet-3.0, jaxrs-1.1, jndi-1.0, appState-1.0, ejbLite-3.1, cdi-1.0].
[INFO    ] CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 5.356 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[INFO    ] SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local application server's memory.
[INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/
[INFO    ] JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is "15".
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [myapp] [/] [/loginpage.jsp]: Initialization successful.
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:28:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 3835 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.46:12949 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:91bbda0f-c95d-4e3a-43cd-a26eb6745303 response_time:1.722074055 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:28:50 +0000] "GET /styles/layout.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 8777 "http://fscproj.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.46:35466 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:dcad0bc3-790f-44f1-5bb9-0febaed00734 response_time:0.013548015 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:28:51 +0000] "GET /images/ibm.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 92824 "http://fscproj.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.43:17662 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:fb136519-b55f-4bff-7c42-95bccaf618c8 response_time:0.013932824 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:28:51 +0000] "GET /images/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 7347 "http://fscproj.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.46:15591 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:f494b027-53da-4c2b-6011-f751e1d58d0a response_time:0.014634660 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:28:51 +0000] "GET /styles/navi.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 3229 "http://fscproj.mybluemix.net/styles/layout.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.46:26003 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:fd46d2d1-db2b-4828-74f4-842b2c3ad729 response_time:0.006212971 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:28:51 +0000] "GET /styles/forms.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 1986 "http://fscproj.mybluemix.net/styles/layout.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.42:50968 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:98690564-68c0-4a80-5fad-21d929b3486b response_time:0.005961185 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:28:51 +0000] "GET /styles/tables.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 924 "http://fscproj.mybluemix.net/styles/layout.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.42:60561 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:cf75f2ff-2fd8-42fa-620f-5977ea24bc79 response_time:0.010175099 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:28:51 +0000] "GET /styles/featured_slide.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 2400 "http://fscproj.mybluemix.net/styles/layout.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.43:24397 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:cd0aa784-5e4d-41f2-73bd-ae68f7f30e8c response_time:0.018511510 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [myapp] [/] [loginclass]: Initialization successful.
Searching through VCAP keys
Key is: sqldb
Service found: SQL Database-fl
Connecting to the database
Finished
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:29:00 +0000] "GET /loginclass?empid=23232I&password=ggggg&SUBMIT=login HTTP/1.1" 302 0 0 "http://fscproj.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.43:13856 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:66350d6c-fc15-4521-69dd-b343cc98ef03 response_time:0.744243093 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [myapp] [/] [/empdetails.jsp]: Initialization successful.
at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: &quot;java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2://75.126.155.153:50000/SQLDB&quot;
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(QueryTagSupport.java:284)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:701)
    ... 2 more
    at com.ibm._jsp._empdetails._jspService(_empdetails.java:204)
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2://75.126.155.153:50000/SQLDB"
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm._jsp._empdetails._jspx_meth_s_query_0(_empdetails.java:259)
    at com.ibm._jsp._empdetails._jspService(_empdetails.java:154)
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException:701'
    at [internal classes]
fscproj.mybluemix.net - [05/08/2015:08:29:01 +0000] "GET /empdetails.jsp HTTP/1.1" 500 0 2052 "http://fscproj.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 75.126.70.43:26112 x_forwarded_for:"122.248.183.22" vcap_request_id:9e5e91ab-43df-4da9-4f47-f57d195ec76b response_time:0.899565979 app_id:a6dc6027-eb2e-499a-83b9-641e15e9dd78}
```

Comment: Provide full stack trace, up to the root cause. But it seems that you miss the JDBC driver, or have an improper version of it.

Comment: still facing same problem  here i provide full stack please check it